# Rails Cast: ActionMailer Email not sent to inbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer, railscasts

The server states that the email was sent to the correct address but I am not getting the message in my inbox.

My Setup_mail.rb file

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings ={
  :address          => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port         => 587,
  :domain           => "gmail.com",
  :user_name        => "my_user_name@gmail.com",
  :password         => "my_password",
  :authentication       => "Plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

My `development.rb` file is:

```
# Don't care if the mailer can't send
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true #default value
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp #default value
```

My `test.rb` file is:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

I have tried multiple variations and am lost.  I am running on a Windows 7 machine. I am running Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.0.7

Can anyone help?

Here is my create method:

```
def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
 if @user.save
   UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
   sign_in @user
   redirect_to @user, :flash => { :success => "Welcome to the Sample App!" }
 else
   @title = "Sign up"
   render 'new'
 end
end
```

My user_mailer.rb
    class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

```
default :from => "my_user_name@gmail.com"

def registration_confirmation(user)
mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Thanks for registering")

end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code from the model and controller that is specific to this mailer?

Comment: I think google requires you to use SSL/TLS.

Comment: @caley Woods:  :enable_starttls_auto => true means that SSL/TLS gets used!

Comment: @andre thanks I missed that line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at your server. I'm pretty sure that you can see in your logs that it's actually trying to send the mail.

The problem is that Google doesn't trust your local IP address and your mails won't get delivered (not even to the spam directory). There is no way to work around this but using a whitelisted server.

If you try your app in production this should normally work, for example deploy your app to heroku to test it.

Comment: This is correct.  I deployed to Heroku and the emailer workered.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes, I checked my /var/log/mail.log  and found the root cause. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try putting in `.deliver` at the end. That fixed this issue for me:

```
mail(:to .....).deliver!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the authentication from a string to a symbol.

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings ={
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "gmail.com",
  :user_name            => "my_user_name@gmail.com",
  :password             => "my_password",
  :authentication       => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: I changed the authentication and email did not hit inbox.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @user797995 it's interesting. The rails guide says that it needs to be a symbol `:plain` but in their example they use"plain" a string.

Comment: I deployed to Heroku and this solved the issue.  however this will still not work in development or test.

Answer (score 0):

You should check that **my_user_name@gmail.com** has actually sent the email. We have had issues with this in the past when sending verification emails out through Gmail's SMTP server, since sending in bulk end up not sending at all.

I suggest you log into my_user_name@gmail.com and verify that there are no problems and that the emails are sent.

If not, you may want try a service like [Send Grid](http://sendgrid.com/) to send outgoing emails.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, I was able to see that in my console mail was sent but in inbox nothing was appearing, one thing is that you can deploy your app on whitelisted server like heroku, or if you want to see just for testing purpose through your local just enable less secure apps in your browser and you should be able to see that email in your inbox
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps